# CloseableHttpAsyncClient not send out http request

Tags: java

I want to use CloseableHttpAsyncClient to send a http request in Async mode. But the request is not send out. When enable comment HttpResponse response = future.get(). It works. But I'd like to know why I need future.get() even I didn't care about the response.
Code is here

```java
public class CloseableHttpAsyncClientTest {

    @Test
    public void whenUseHttpAsyncClient_thenCorrect() throws Exception {
        CloseableHttpAsyncClient client = HttpAsyncClients.createDefault();
        client.start();
        HttpDelete request = new HttpDelete("http://www.bing.com");
        Future<HttpResponse> future = client.execute(request, null);
//      The delete request will send out if we remove comment here. We just want to send out delete http
//      request but not care about the response     
//      HttpResponse response = future.get(); 
        client.close();
    }
}
```

The console like this

```
20:28:48.930 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec - [exchange: 1] start execution
20:28:48.941 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: default
20:28:48.950 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
20:28:48.951 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalHttpAsyncClient - [exchange: 1] Request connection for {}->http://www.bing.com:80
20:28:48.953 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection request: [route: {}->http://www.bing.com:80][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
20:28:48.976 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection manager is shutting down
20:28:49.003 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection manager shut down
```

After I enable the comments. Like this. It works.

```java
public class CloseableHttpAsyncClientTest {

    @Test
    public void whenUseHttpAsyncClient_thenCorrect() throws Exception {
        CloseableHttpAsyncClient client = HttpAsyncClients.createDefault();
        client.start();
        HttpDelete request = new HttpDelete("http://www.bing.com");
        Future<HttpResponse> future = client.execute(request, null);
//      The delete request will send out if we remove comment here. We just want to send out delete http
//      request but not care about the response     
        HttpResponse response = future.get(); 
        client.close();
    }
}
```

From the log, we can see. The http delete has been send out.

```
20:39:15.998 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec - [exchange: 1] start execution
......
......

20:39:16.137 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> DELETE / HTTP/1.1
20:39:16.137 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Host: www.bing.com
......
......


20:39:16.142 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "DELETE / HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
20:39:16.142 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: www.bing.com[\r][\n]"
20:39:16.142 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
20:39:16.142 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpAsyncClient/4.1.4 (Java/1.8.0_202)[\r][\n]"
20:39:16.143 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
20:39:16.143 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch - http-outgoing-0 [ACTIVE] Request ready
20:39:16.143 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG 
......

20:39:16.209 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection manager shut down
```

Comment: I think I have find the answer.

Comment: try `client.close(CloseMode.GRACEFUL);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
Future<HttpResponse> future = client.execute(request, null);
```

*client.execute* will send out http request in Async way. It will take another thread to complete the http request.

```java
HttpResponse response = future.get();
```

*future.get()* will block the main thread until client.execute complete and fill the response into future. Without this, the client will be close before http request send out. Cos http request send out by one thread, but client close be closed by main thread. So, main thread need be blocked until future.get() get the result by another thread.